# Refresh model SAPUI5

Tags: model, sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm developing SAP Fiori app with master detail template. 
i'm having troubles,I need to update a particular data every 5 seconds, but i don't want to refresh the entire model because it takes too long to render.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: can you give an example?
Is that particular data part of model data?

Comment: it's dificult to explain,  yes it's a particular data part of model data. I only want to refresh detail not master, but those have the same model.

Comment: implement get entity (NOT ENTITYSET) for that detail part.
I am assuming, you want to refresh only item of the whole data set..
Then bind that to the detail with new model and refresh with time interval of your wish

Answer (score 5):

You could try to [refresh the Binding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Binding.html#refresh) on your control.
For example:

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("myList").getBinding("items").refresh();
```

Depending on the type of Model you are using this would send a more focused request.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to [refresh the element binding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Binding.html#refresh) of the view or control.

```
this.getView().getElementBinding().refresh(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following. Set a modelDetail for your detail, and a modelMaster for your master. Put the same data in both models when you initialize your app.

When you want to update part of your data in a specific model, use

```
modelDetail .setProperty(yourPath, yourNewProperty);
```

this will automatically update all bindings for the changed properties, only in the detail view.

Answer (score -1):

You should use two way binding.
https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/c72b922fdb59422496661000165d7ff1.html

Then if you have an oData model you can set the property `refresh` to 5.
This will refresh the oData-Model every 5 seconds.
Than the two way binding will update the specific parts of your view, without having to refresh the entire view.